# Como buscar en Cloud Firestore por un campo en especifico? (android)

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

Tengo una coleccion llamada perfil_usuario en la cual quiero buscar por email pero no obtengo los datos, viene un array vacio:

Metodo para buscar:

```
private void buscar(String email) {      
    db.collection("perfil_usuario")
            .whereEqualTo("email", email)
            .get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                            Log.d("ver", document.getId() + " => " + document.getData());
                        }
                    } else {
                        Log.d("error", "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

Le he pasado valores que estoy seguro que estan en la base.
aqui la estructura del documento:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Cuando dices que no obtienes respuesta, a qué te refieres?

Comment: Aun necesitas ayuda?